# Micrometer timer metrics coming as 0 in application insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, micrometer

We are publishing micrometer counter and timer metrics from our azure app to application insight. We are counting hits to an API and the time it took to process the request in the micrometer counter and timer. The metrics are coming properly in local environment as seen in the jconsole screenshot
[image: Timer metrics coming properly in local debugging]

However, when viewed in azure application insight, there are a few observations:

- The timer metrics value is mostly 0.
- Micrometer counter and timer are updated when a request hits the API. However, we see that the counter metric is captured in application insight at a regular interval but the timer metric is captured only when a request comes. We see this by looking for the timer and counter metrics in the customMetrics table.

[image: Timer metrics mostly are 0 in azure AI]

Can someone please help us to resolve these issues?

Comment: Did you use custom code to publish the metrics to AI? If so, how does it look like and if not, then what are you using?

Comment: We are not using any custom code rather using what is specified in the official documentation. It is exactly like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent#send-custom-metrics-by-using-micrometer